# how to create a list menu in to layers with 100% width?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a menu in a list form, I want the menu to be in two rows one row with the first the first level  and the second row with the second level . The problem I've been fighting with is that I want each row to be 100%.

this is what I want to result to look like, exepet one thing -
[image]

I don't want the second row of the menu to cover the image.

please hep me!

```
<ul class="levelOne">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4
       <ul class="LevelTwo">
           <li>4.1</li>
           <li>4.2</li>
           <li>4.3</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position relative on the first UL

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
:root{width: 100vw; height: 100vh}
.levelOne{width: 100%}
.levelOne, .LevelTwo{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}
.levelOne li, .LevelTwo li{display: inline-block; list-style: none; padding: 8px 14px;color: #0b405c;cursor: pointer}
.levelOne{
  text-align: right
 }
.levelOne >li:hover{
  color: #999;
  background: #ccc
}
.levelOne li:hover .LevelTwo{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
.LevelTwo{
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0b405c
}
.LevelTwo li:hover{color: white}
```

```html
<ul class="levelOne">
   <li>Fastigheter</li>
   <li>Projekt</li>
   <li>För Investerare</li>
   <li>Kontakta oss</li>
   <li>Om K2A
       <ul class="LevelTwo">
           <li>Organisation</li>
           <li>Affäraside Och strategi</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```